# Cakephp(CakeDC) Search Plugin custom filter methods

Tags: php, search, cakephp, cakedc

I am trying to use the [cakephp search plugin](http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/cakephp_search_plugin) and I am having problems using the query method to filter results. I created a function called findByLength() which is declared in the $filterArgs array. I'm not sure if the array i'm building out is right. When I look at the sql statements it looks like its not even being invoked. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
<?php
// findByLength() is not affecting the sql like expected. Any ideas?
// using http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/cakephp_search_plugin

    public $filterArgs = array(
            array('name' => 'name', 'type' => 'like'),
            array('name' => 'search', 'type' => 'like', 'field' => 'Trail.description'),
            array('name' => 'type','type'=>'string'),
            array('name'=>'dogs_allowed','type'=>'value'),
            array('name'=>'area_id','type'=>'value'),
            array('name' => 'length', 'type' => 'query', 'method' => 'findByLength', 'field' => 'Trail.length'),
            array('name' => 'state_id','field'=>'Area.state_id', 'type' => 'value'),
            array('name'=>'created_by_pt','field'=>'Trail.created_by','type'=> 'value'),
            //array('name'=>'created_by_user','field'=>'Trail.created_by','type'=> 'value'),
 );
    public function findByLength(){

        if(empty($data['Trail']['length'])){
            return array();
        }
        switch($data['Trail']['length']){
            case 0:
                return array('AND'=> array($this->alias.'.length >='=> $data['Trail']['length'],
                                                                     $this->alias.'.length <'=> $data['Trail']['length'] + 3)

                                );
            break;
            case 3:
                return array('AND'=> array($this->alias.'.length >='=> $data['Trail']['length'],
                                                                     $this->alias.'.length >'=> $data['Trail']['length'] + 3)

                                );
            break;
            case 6:
            return array('AND'=> array($this->alias.'.length >='=> $data['Trail']['length'],
                                                                 $this->alias.'.length <'=> $data['Trail']['length'] + 4)

                            );
            break;
            case 10:
            return array('AND'=> array($this->alias.'.length >='=> $data['Trail']['length'])

                            );
            break;
        }

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was referencing the wrong array keys.

```
$data['Trail']['length'] ended up being $data['length']
```

and changed

```
public function findByLength(){
```

to

```
public function findByLength($data = array()){
```